# ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, clob, listagg

I have union of 3 views. The data types in the views are same but i m getting an error "ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression". The last union has a clob converted to varchar to match with the above views.I am giving the code below. Please help me solving this issue

```
SELECT
ROWNUM rownum_1,
customer_trx_id,
customer_trx_line_id,
item_name,
quantity_invoiced,
unit_selling_price,
extended_amount,
line_number,
row_num,
line_description,
tax_perc,
line_total,
tax_amount,
uom,
po_line FROM
apps.gnet_bpa_inv_lines_cons
WHERE
    :p_summary = 'N'
AND
    customer_trx_id = 3725097
UNION ALL
SELECT
ROWNUM rownum_1,
customer_trx_id,
customer_trx_line_id,
item_name,
quantity_invoiced,
unit_selling_price,
extended_amount,
line_number,
row_num,
line_description,
tax_perc,
line_total,
tax_amount,
uom,
po_line
FROM
apps.gnet_bpa_inv_lines_cons_summ
WHERE
    :p_summary = 'Y'
AND
    customer_trx_id = 3725097
UNION ALL
SELECT
MAX(ROWNUM) rownum_1,
customer_trx_id AS customer_trx_id,
MAX(customer_trx_line_id) AS customer_trx_line_id,
dbms_lob.substr(
    XMLAGG(xmlelement(e,item_name,',').extract('//text()') ORDER BY 
po_line).getclobval(),
    4000,
    1
) AS item_name,
LISTAGG(quantity_invoiced,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS 
quantity_invoiced,
MAX(unit_selling_price) AS unit_selling_price,
SUM(extended_amount) AS extended_amount,
MAX(line_number) AS line_number,
LISTAGG(row_num,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS row_num,
dbms_lob.substr(
    XMLAGG(xmlelement(e,line_description,',').extract('//text()') ORDER BY 
po_line).getclobval(),
    4000,
    1
) AS line_description,
LISTAGG(tax_perc,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS tax_perc,
LISTAGG(tax_amount,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS tax_amount,
SUM(line_total) AS line_total,
LISTAGG(uom,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS uom,
po_line
FROM
apps.gnet_bpa_inv_lines_cons
WHERE
    :p_summary = 'P'
AND
    customer_trx_id = 3725097
GROUP BY
po_line,
customer_trx_id
ORDER BY rownum_1;
```

Comment: Have you done any work yet to find out which part of the query is causing the error?

Comment: what are the original data types of the columns?

Answer (score 2):

```
LISTAGG(tax_perc,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS tax_perc,
LISTAGG(tax_amount,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY po_line) AS tax_amount,
```

are char/varchar datatypes in the last union where as they are numeric/decimal in first two sections. check for the othr columns like this as well and your problem should be resolved.